# What should I eat during a tournament?

Tags: tournament

I was wondering, what should I eat during and before a big tournament? I've already learned that sugar is a *no-go* for me for the most part... Any advice? Thanks in advance, ~CSS

---

> My question is different from [Eating and drinking before and during a game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/eating-and-drinking-before-and-during-a-game).
>   
>  I find that sugar affects me adversely, and all the answers on the other thread are referencing sugar... I need something substantial...

Comment: Nobody can tell you. You have to experiment and find what works best *for you*.

Comment: For a more substantial answer, consider a bounty on the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...what should I eat during and before a big tournament?

Try taking a look at an article that FM Mike Klein wrote for Chess Life, the USCF publication, in 2008.  It's available [*here*](http://chess.jliptrap.us/grandmasterdiet.htm).

It recommends nutrition for before and during play, but it also emphasizes the importance of a good diet *all the time*.